# How to change UILabel font size corresponding to uitabelviewcell frame when working with self sizing cells?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have done functionality to select address from list of available addresses. In this demo, for table view, I created custom cell which automatically adjusted for text inside UILabel (i.e. address field)

Problem is that When the table view is first displayed, I found font size of "address label" in cells is not sized properly. But when I scroll the table view, then cells are displayed with correct font size.

***see below images:***

**Problem**

[image]

**What I want**

[image]

I get second behaviour after reloading tableview inside viewDidAppear. But it flickering my screen. Please help. Any help appreciated.

**my code**

**view controller.m**

```
#import "AddressListViewController.h"
#import "AddressListTableViewCell.h"
#import "Utils.h"

@interface AddressListViewController () <UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate>

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *addressListTableView;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSArray *arraySavedAddresses;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableParagraphStyle *paragraphStyle;

@end

@implementation AddressListViewController

#pragma mark - lazy instantiation

- (NSArray *)arraySavedAddresses {
    if (!_arraySavedAddresses)
        _arraySavedAddresses = @[@"Studio 103, The Business Centre, 61 Wellfield Road, Roath, Cardiff, CF24 3DG",
                                 @"Castor Richardson, P.O. Box 902 3472 Ullamcorper Street, Lynchburg DC 29738, (268) 442-2428, Mob. 9999999999",
                                 @"Maharashtra India",
                                 @"Office 33, 27 Colmore Row, Birmingham, England, B3 2EW"];
    return _arraySavedAddresses;
}

- (NSMutableParagraphStyle *)paragraphStyle {
    if (!_paragraphStyle) {
        _paragraphStyle = [[NSMutableParagraphStyle alloc] init];
        [_paragraphStyle setAlignment:NSTextAlignmentLeft];
        [_paragraphStyle setLineSpacing:5.0f];
    }
    return _paragraphStyle;
}

#pragma mark - view controllers life cycle methods

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [self.view layoutIfNeeded];

    [self.addressListTableView setDataSource:self];
    [self.addressListTableView setDelegate:self];

    [self.addressListTableView setEstimatedRowHeight:80];
}

#pragma mark - table view delegate methods

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return [self.arraySavedAddresses count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    AddressListTableViewCell *addressListTableViewCell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"AddressListTableViewCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    [Utils updateLabelFontSize:addressListTableViewCell.labelUsername ForInitialHeight:24 andInitialSize:24];
    [addressListTableViewCell.labelAddress setFont:[addressListTableViewCell.labelAddress.font fontWithSize:[addressListTableViewCell.labelUsername bounds].size.height * 0.666667]];

    [addressListTableViewCell.labelUsername setText:@"Demo User"];

    NSString *labelText = [self.arraySavedAddresses objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];
    NSMutableAttributedString *attributedString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:labelText];
    [attributedString addAttribute:NSParagraphStyleAttributeName value:self.paragraphStyle range:NSMakeRange(0, [labelText length])];
    [addressListTableViewCell.labelAddress setAttributedText:attributedString];

    return addressListTableViewCell;
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    return UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
}

@end
```

**tableviewcell.m**

```
#import "AddressListTableViewCell.h"
#import "Utils.h"

@implementation AddressListTableViewCell

- (void)awakeFromNib {
    [super awakeFromNib];

    [[self.viewAddressInfo layer] setBorderColor:[[UIColor lightGrayColor] CGColor]];
}

- (void)layoutSubviews {
    [super layoutSubviews];

}

- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated {
    [super setSelected:selected animated:animated];

    // Configure the view for the selected state
}

- (IBAction)buttonRemoveAddressAction:(id)sender {
    NSLog(@"Cancel Pressed");
}
```

**tableviewcell.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface AddressListTableViewCell : UITableViewCell

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *viewAddressInfo;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *labelUsername;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *labelAddress;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *imageViewRadioSelection;

@end
```

Comment: Where are you resizing the label/font ?

Comment: @hi tushar. Just give me a min. I also upload my code. I'm resizing label inside cellforrowatindexpath

Comment: @andrea - problem is that, I am adjusting fontsize of uilabel proportional to  [myUIlabel_address bounds].size.height. But In cellforrowatindexpath I am not getting actual height of label

Comment: Not using autolayout?

Comment: @bhavuk - I used autolayout. But problem with autolayout is that cells fresh from the storyboard had the width of the abstract size device, and they didn't get resized to the real width of the view controller until after the row height calculation. Thus I forced width of cell equal to width of table view

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally after searching long, I found the solution. I only forced new frame for uitableviewcell inside cellforrowatindexpath.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    AddressListTableViewCell *addressListTableViewCell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"AddressListTableViewCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    CGFloat tableWidth = [tableView bounds].size.width;
    if ([addressListTableViewCell frame].size.width != tableWidth) {
        CGRect forcedFrame = [addressListTableViewCell frame];
        forcedFrame.size.width = tableWidth;
        forcedFrame.size.height = 32000;

        [addressListTableViewCell setFrame:forcedFrame];

        forcedFrame.origin.x = [[addressListTableViewCell contentView] frame].origin.x;
        forcedFrame.origin.y = [[addressListTableViewCell contentView] frame].origin.y;

        [[addressListTableViewCell contentView] setFrame:forcedFrame];
        [addressListTableViewCell layoutIfNeeded];
    }

    [Utils updateLabelFontSize:addressListTableViewCell.labelUsername ForInitialHeight:24 andInitialSize:24];
    [addressListTableViewCell.labelAddress setFont:[addressListTableViewCell.labelAddress.font fontWithSize:[addressListTableViewCell.labelUsername bounds].size.height * 0.666667]];

    [addressListTableViewCell.labelUsername setText:@"Demo User"];

    NSString *labelText = [self.arraySavedAddresses objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];
    NSMutableAttributedString *attributedString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:labelText];
    [attributedString addAttribute:NSParagraphStyleAttributeName value:self.paragraphStyle range:NSMakeRange(0, [labelText length])];
    [addressListTableViewCell.labelAddress setAttributedText:attributedString];

    return addressListTableViewCell;
}
```

Got a good hint on this site: http://useyourloaf.com/blog/self-sizing-table-view-cells/

Answer (score 0):

In interface builder, change autoshrink to minimum font scale and set it to 0.5-0.7

Comment: please see my code. I recently updated. If I changed font scale and used autoshrink, It only adjusts width of label. Not height. So it clipped off label. Also I want proportional label sizes